# Azure apim developer portal customization issue

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am new to APIM, facing issue when I tries to add maps & pop-up kind of widgets in Developer portal. before adding widgets it was working fine but once I added widgets in Home page shows an error message as
"Oops, something went wrong".
[Could not get object 'files/e0987ca1-f458-b546-7697-7be594b35583'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3wKe.png)

I would like to display well formatted document to our users in the Developer portal,so suggest some good docs or resourceses on customization of Dev portal.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: This was the error,im facing - Could not get object 'files/e0987ca1-f458-b546-7697-7be594b35583'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround to save the changes made to layout in APIM developer portal as following:

1. Go to the **developer portal** of the APIM Instance > Click on **APIs** option on right top corner > Click on **Edit Layouts** option comes in the bottom right corner >

[image]

Edit your layout by adding the required options like **List of APIs** or ***API History*** or ***Widgets*** and then click on ***Save button*** is available on left side.

[image]

[image]

After making selection, Save option will be enabled to apply changes.

**References:**

1. [Customize Azure API developer Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize)
2. [Implement Widgets in the Azure APIM Developer Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-implement-widgets)

#### Updated Answer:

If you have issues when creating the widgets in the Azure APIM Developer portal, Please raise a request to Microsoft Service Team or please send your service name to [apimportalfeedback@microsoft.com](http://apimportalfeedback@microsoft.com.).

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/630